# phpmyadmin showing error regarding mysqli, but its already installed

Tags: 14.04, mysql, phpmyadmin

first screen shot of error showing phpmyadmin error

[image]

second screen shot after using sudo with mysqli

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/566421) Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the PHP MySQL module is actually there:

```
php -m | grep mysqli
```

If the above command returns nothing probably something goes wrong during the installation of the MySQL module. So you can try to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php-mysql
```

Then **restart the web server**, **flush your browser's cache** and **reload the page**.

---

The PHP modules are enabled through `.ini` files located in `/etc/php/<php.version>/mods-available` and their binaries are located in `/usr/lib/php`, here is example output from my system:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini 
; configuration for php mysql module
; priority=20
extension=mysqli.so

$ sudo find /usr/lib/php -type f -name 'mysqli.so'
/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mysqli extension. You may open a terminal and run this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysqli
```

After that, make sure the extension is enabled. You will have to check your php.ini location. Probably is located here:

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

Edit the ini file and look for mysqli. Uncomment the line by removing ;

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

After all that you will have to restart apache service by executing:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

And reload PhpMyAdmin Page. You may also need to install some other extensions like mbstring.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Hello, Martin. I'm sure there is no `php7.2-mysqli` module, but there should have `php7.2-mysql`. To mange the PHP configuration for Apache you should edit `/etc/php/<php.version>/apache2/php.ini`, but the better way to enable PHP modules (both for cli and apache) is through the `.ini` files located in `/etc/php/<php.version>/mods-available`. Also if you are using `php-mysql` (without version) it should manage the PHP version automatically. And finally it is not mentioned that this is Apache :)